# Maths area question

Tags: calculus, area

I want to answer the follow question.

> I’ve worked out the area of the circle to be 200.96

Where would I go from here?

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to go from here?

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking sorry forgot to attach the image I have now

Comment: Hint: area = $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin(c)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint $$\text{Area of triangle}=\frac{1}{2}(a)(b)\sin(C)$$ where a,b are sides and C is the included angle. So we get $70=\frac{1}{2}(8)(19)\sin(A)$ so $\sin(A)=\frac{35}{38}$ you can get value of angle A in radians and find the area of sector as $\frac{A}{2\pi}\pi (8)^2$